# Странный ответ команды sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, unix

Комадна `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` отдает ответ:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-18+deb8u6) but 2.19-18 is installed
>
> libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-18+deb8u6) but 2.19-18 is installed
>
> libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-18+deb8u6) but 2.19-18 is installed
>
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Скажите, что это значит?

Comment: в чём заключается вопрос то? )

Comment: В том, что не должно так работать и нужно как-то поправить )

Comment: сделайте новую виртуальную машину и попробуйте на ней

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, дак вам же пишут: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.`. Запустите `apt-get -f install` и попробуйте ещё раз)

Comment: Где ты такие кривые виртуалки берёшь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совет выполнить команду

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

скорее всего, ничего не даст. Опция -f приказывает сделать это, несмотря на все несоответствия. Смотрите, что пишет apt:

```
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-18+deb8u6) but 2.19-18 is installed
```

Это означает, что apt пытается уствановить пакет libc6-dev и этот пакет зависит пакета libc6 (что очевидно), а версия этого пакета должна быть 2.19-18+deb8u6. А в Вашей системе установлен этот пакет с версией  2.19-18. Т.е. версии ОТЛИЧАЮТСЯ. И apt не может найти в текущих репозитариях версию 2.19-18+deb8u6.

Рискну предположить, что в процессе эксплуатации системы Вы как-то меняли репозитарии. Или подключали "левые". В результате этого сложилась такая ситуация, когда часть пакетов в системе взяты из одного репозитария, а часть - из другого. И они различаются версиями.

Разрулить такую ситуацию достаточно сложно... Нужно удалять все пакеты, для которых нет нужных зависимостей, а затем инсталлировать их заново. Зачастую бывает проще переустановить ОС. :-(

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Сергей!

Answer (score 0):

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>   ...
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

у установленных на данный момент пакетов (перечислены в тексте сообщения) есть неудовлетворённые на данный момент зависимости.

чтобы исправить эту «нуудовлетворённость», надо выполнить предложенную в сообщении команду:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```